# How do I make grid axes invisible for a pandas dataframe hist()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is what i want to do, histogram plots of all columns of a dataframe but without the grid axes.  The below code works, but preferably I'd like a more elegant solution (such as passing an argument to hist)

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.asarray([50]*25+[30]*10)
X2 = np.asarray([90]*10+[20]*25)
X3 = np.asarray([10]*15+[70]*20)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([X, X2, X3]).T)


def plot_hists(df, nbins=10, figsize=(8, 8), disable_axis_labels = True):
    plt.close('all')
    grid_of_ax_hists = df.hist(bins=nbins, figsize=figsize)
    if disable_axis_labels:
        for row in grid_of_ax_hists:
            for ax in row:
                ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
                ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
    plt.show()

    df.hist()
    plt.subplots()

plot_hists(df, nbins=10, figsize=(8, 8), disable_axis_labels = True)
```

Answer (score 7):

Even so this thread is kinda old, i'd like to add a working solution because i've just had the same issue.

At least in pandas 0.18

df.hist() takes all possible plotting keywords from pandas.DataFrame.plot

```
df.hist(grid=False)
```

works easily.. and there is no need of dealing with matplotlib axes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
df.hist(bins=nbins, ax=ax1)
ax1.grid(b=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, I get 'UserWarning: To output multiple subplots, the figure containing the passed axes is being cleared
  "is being cleared", UserWarning'

and then the plot that is output still has the axis